# SQl Select data that appears in one or more sets

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a many to many relationship

```
code1 code2
  1    10       <-- Desired (1 appears more than once)
  1    11       <-- Desired (1 appears more than once)
  1    17       <-- Desired (1 appears more than once)
  2    10
  3    11       <-- Desired (3 appears more than once)
  3    17       <-- Desired (3 appears more than once)
  4    10
  5    10
```

... And I want to write a **single SQL query** whose results are this:

```
code1 
  1          <-- This result appears because 1 appears more than once above
  3         <-- This result appears because 3 appears more than once above
```

(i.e, a single SQL query that returns all rows for which any data in the `code1` is that is tied to 11 and 17)...

What SQL can I write?  Is it possible?

Comment: just a side note mysq and sql server are 2 different dbs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY and HAVING to filter these out. Try this:

```
SELECT code1
FROM myTable
GROUP BY code1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This will pull all 'code1' values that appear more than once by grouping them, and seeing which groups have more than one row.

**EDIT**

If you want to include conditions on other columns, you can first write a query that gets only the rows you want (as you said in the comments, where code2 is equal to 11 or 17) like this:

```
SELECT code1, code2
FROM myTable
WHERE code2 = 11 OR code2 = 17;
```

Then, you can apply the above filter on that query. You don't need code2 in your result set:

```
SELECT code1
FROM myTable
WHERE code2 = 11 OR code2 = 17
GROUP BY code1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I tested this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf681/1) and it worked.

Comment: How can I be more specific to 'code1' that has `code2` as 11 and 17?

Comment: @DeveloperNo.1 . .  You can ask another question.  This answer answers this question.

Comment: I mentioned this in my question. I am not adding anything new to the original question.

Comment: @DeveloperNo.1 You can include a where clause. I edited my answer. I can see where Gordon is coming from, as you barely hinted at 11 and 17. You said you wanted values that appeared more than once, so that's what I gave you originally.

Comment: Thank you! I have been wrecking my brains over this. I guess I need to refresh my sql.